# Search result on bases of file name using Microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph) for OneDrive (personal and business) integration. I am able to get content using the [Search API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_search) but it is not returning the results expected per the documentation.

I have also compared response using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer) with same request.

I am using these api requests:

`GET /me/drive/search(q='doc')` when searching on root.

`GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/search(q='{search-text}')` when searching on non-root folder

These calls are not returning all of the files I would expect. I am not able to files which are 0 byte (empty).

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this issue. Just to clarify, you're saying `search` isn't returning 0 byte files? I created `New Text Document.txt` with 0 bytes and was able to return in in the search results. Am I misunderstanding what you're seeing?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT No, you understood correctly. I not able to see all the results. It is not returning all the files containing name of search keyword.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Can you please guide me to get all the records containing search keyword using graph search api request. Thank you in advance. Using above api, i am not receiving all the records in results.

Comment: How many are you getting and how many do you expect to get?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Please see this link https://pastebin.com/naYvP8Ve .

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT For see the attachment link - https://imagebin.ca/v/3YepoeSFDwxR

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT have you got time to see above link?

Comment: Can you add the JSON result you're receiving to your question?

Answer (score 0):

search not return specific type of files, like .png, .jpg,.md,.js, maybe even more. for my testing, it will return .pdf, docx, odp and xls